# Clearing redirect cache in Chrome and Safari

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari

I used to have a self-signed certificate on my test site, such that http://example.com redirected to https://example.com. I have since removed the certificate as well as the redirect, such that the server acts exactly as before (i.e. on port 80). However, I am having trouble getting my system to understand this.

I have deleted the certificate in Keychain Access on OS X, and I have cleared Chrome's cache. What happens is that when I try to access the site, the browser redirects to the HTTPS version, but since the server no longer accepts this, I get an error. The same is true for Safari, which does the same thing. It does work in Firefox because I had not visited the site when the HTTPS version was active. I have tried to restart all browsers and restart the operating system multiple times. Nothing works to reset this behavior.

So, both Chrome and Safari somehow cached this redirect, and clearing caches and restarting does not work, neither does waiting (this has been a problem for months).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to test the cache in Chrome... open the Object Inspector. Goto the Network tab and make sure the "Disable cache" checkbox is checked. Now load your page - do you still get the "cached" redirect?

Comment: @w3d Yes, Chrome still goes to the HTTPS version.